# Time value handling on Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time

I am struggling to understand what is happening within a script I am developing.
The situation is the following: on cell B2 I have inputted 06:45PM, which is automatically taken as time format by GSheets.
On the dummy script, I have the following dummy code:

```
function whathour() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var t=ss.getRange("B2").getValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(t);
  Logger.log(t);
}
```

(I am using alert as a debug tool, yes).

The amusing result is that the value alerted (or logged) when the function is run is `[17-09-14 11:15:25:006 CEST] Sat Dec 30 19:09:05 GMT+00:09 1899.` !

I would have focused on the possibility of problematic timezones if I hadnt seen that, well, 18:45 and 19:09 can never be the same time in regards to different timezones!

I am trying to collect just the 18:45 out of the cell in order to do certain time duration operations, but this first step is blocking me. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

**Edit:** attached an image of what I described:
[image]

Comment: not in Sydney anymore, CEST is correct.
Locale and Time zone should be the server side, as this is running on google sheets, shouldnt it? in any case, how may I provide said info?

Comment: Attached the screenshot of what I described. Any other ideas? As I mentioned, it is strange that timezone has anything to do, as the _minutes_ should be the same... any constructive opinion?

Comment: Locale: Spain
Time zone: (GMT+1) Madrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)? This retrieves the displayed value of the cell. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function whathour() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var t=ss.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(t);
  Logger.log(t);
}
```

Comment: That made the trick in the end! it does not store the value as a Date object, but I can work with that....! 
Thanks,

Comment: @ggonmar Welcome. Thank you, too. If you want to use the data as Date, for example, by using ``var t2=ss.getRange("B2").getValue();``, both ``t`` which is string data and ``t2`` which is Date can be used.